# AngularJS ng-repeat to create divs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to use AngularJs to create some div structure but it doesn't work at all.
How am I supposed to use range ?

```
<div ng-controller = "gameController">
    <div class="table">
        <div ng-repeat = "i in [] | range:game.nrLines">
            <div class="trow">
                <div ng-repeat = "j in [] | range:game.nrCols">
                    <span class="element">
                        <img src="img/elep.png" class="element" data-col = {{j}} data-line= {{i}}>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the Angular code :

```
var gameApp = angular.module("gameApp", []);
gameApp.filter('range', function() {
    return function(input) {
        for (var i=0; i<input; i++) {
            input.push(i);          
        }
        return input;
    }
});

gameApp.controller("gameController", function($scope) {
    $scope.game = new Game();
    $scope.nrCols = $scope.game.matrix.getNrCols;
    $scope.nrLines = $scope.game.matrix.getNrLines;
});
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filter is missing a parameter for the range. Input is what you're going to be returning from the filter, so you just need to add another parameter for the actual count:

```
gameApp.filter('range', function() {
    return function(input, count) {
        for (var i=0; i<count; i++)
            input.push(i);          
        return input;
    }
});
```

I've made a plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rhl21Jzri53jNOMEDA6G) to help